# JavaFx AudioClip : URL don't work when the audio file is placed inside src folder of the project?

Tags: java, javafx

**My Code**

```
package main;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.media.AudioClip;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Font font = Font.loadFont( Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/TRON.TTF"), 10);

        //ImageView image = new ImageView(new Image("file:outside/bell.png"));

       ImageView image = new ImageView(new Image("resources/images/redseven.png"));

       //This works when file is outside src folder
        //AudioClip audio = new AudioClip("file:sounds/win.wav");

        //doesn't work
       //AudioClip audio = new AudioClip("file:resources/sounds/win.wav");

        //doesn't work
        AudioClip audio = new AudioClip("resources/sounds/win.wav");

        audio.play();



        VBox pane = new VBox();
        Label label = new Label("Text");
        label.setStyle("-fx-font-family:'Tron'; -fx-font-size: 50px;-fx-text-fill: red");

        pane.getChildren().addAll(label, image);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**My Project directory**

[image]

**Output**

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: uri.getScheme() ==
>   null! uri == 'resources/sounds/win.wav'

The image url's work when they are outside src folder and inside src folder. When they are outside I have to include "file:" before the url as shown in the code.

Audioclip irls work when they are file is outside src. But doesn't work when it's inside.

**EDIT**

Doing this works. But I'm not really sure why?

```
AudioClip audio = new AudioClip("file:src/resources/sounds/win.wav");
```

I added the src folder also to the url and then added "file:" infront of it.
Why doesn't it work  with relative path? The image is loaded without any problem.

Comment: Usually you use `SomeClassInstance.getReource(<path in source>).toExternalForm()` for resources. Some IDEs seem to mess this up when resources are not properly added though...

Comment: @fabian can you please give an example of how to get resources using that method?